# Python - List not in correct format

Tags: python, json, string, list

I am reading JSON data and extracting its only keys which are names. Afterwards, removing @ characters using regex and converting all my data into lowercase. In the end, I am inserting it into a list but the inserted data is not what I want. Can someone please assist me.

```
with open('rawtext.json','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

    names_list = []
    for x in data:
        names_list.append(x['name'])
    # Modified_string = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9_\s]+', " ", str(names_list))- It will remove only @ symbol
    modified_string = re.sub(r'[@]+', ' ', str(names_list))
    new_string = (modified_string.lower())
    string_to_list = new_string.split(',')
    print(string_to_list)
```

**Current Output:**

["['apache http server'", " 'angularjs'", " 'amazon ec2'", " 'amazon s3'", " 'android sdk'", " 'android studio'", " 'amazon cloudfront'", " 'aws lambda'", " 'asp.net'", " 'atom'", " 'ansible'", " 'apache tomcat'", " 'amazon rds'", " 'amazon route 53'", " 'amazon ec2 container service'", " 'aws elastic load balancing (elb)'", " 'amazon cloudwatch'", " 'asana'", " 'amazon ses'", " 'animate.css '", " 'angular 2'", " 'addthis'", " 'amazon dynamodb'", " 'apache spark'", " 'apache maven'", " 'dbforge compare bundle for oracle']"]

**The output which I want:**

['apache http server', 'angularjs', 'amazon ec2', 'amazon s3', 'android sdk', 'android studio', 'amazon cloudfront', 'aws lambda', 'asp.net', 'atom', 'ansible', 'apache tomcat', 'amazon rds', 'amazon route 53', 'amazon ec2 container service', 'aws elastic load balancing (elb)', 'amazon cloudwatch', 'asana', 'amazon ses', 'animate.css ', 'angular 2', 'addthis', 'amazon dynamodb', 'apache spark', 'apache maven', 'dbforge compare bundle for oracle']

Thank you for your cooperation and assistance.[image]

Comment: Can you give us an example of what `x['name']` is? Are these just strings? What are some `print(repr(x['name']))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you convert the list to a string, replace the @ symbol and then try to break it up back into a list again. You should be able to do the replacement while reading the strings.

```
with open('rawtext.json','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
result = [x["name"].replace("@", " ") for x in data]
```

And if you don't need to keep the json data, that can reduce to

```
with open('rawtext.json','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    result = [x["name"].replace("@", " ") for x in json.load(f)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's working now.